# 2-2-2 bios beep code on Dell MIG41R M/B

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios, dell-vostro

I have recently acquired a Dell Vostro with a MIG41R motherboard. The PC gave me a 2-2-2 bios beep code, so I opened it up and realized it didn't have and RAM and the HDD was disconnected.

I bought a stick of [Corsair DDR3 1333 4GB RAM](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Corsair-CMX4GX3M1A1333C9-Performance-Desktop-Memory/dp/B003ZDJ42O/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1426682885&sr=8-2&keywords=ddr3%201333), which is compatible as far as I'm aware. I installed the RAM and reconnected the HDD. I am still getting the code 2-2-2.

I've tried both slots, removing the CMOS and checked that everything else is connected.

Does anyone have any ideas if this RAM is actually compatible with this mobo, or have a list of bios codes that definitely relate to this board?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to confirm your system supports the memory you installed because the code indicates you have a memory error.

Comment: What am I looking at terms of compatibility. DDR3 and speed 1333 both are fine. Anything else?

Comment: @ramhound, any advice on how I can confirm compatibility? do I need to match anything beyond DDRx and speed?

Answer (score 0):

> **1-3-1 through 2-4-4**
>
> Memory modules not being properly identified or used

---

Source [Beep Codes and PSA Diagnostic Chart](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/w/desktop/3624.beep-codes-and-psa-diagnostic-chart)